# same tomcat singleton for multiple WAR files

Tags: java, tomcat, singleton

I'm deploying multiple WAR files in my tomcat containing different instances of the same app.
each WAR file is containing a Class acting as a Singleton but this Singleton is getting the same values for each WAR I'm deploying...event If I need different value for each (DB parameters, port, etc,...)
I read that as Singleton depends on the same ClassLoader as contained in the same JVM, this behavior is normal, but I would need to get a singleton instance independent for each WAR file I'm deploying.

is there any configuration of the tomcat server to ensure I have a different Singleton instance for each WAR instance ?

Comment: Do you deploy the same war file just with different contexts?, if so, this means that you have the same class with the same values in all the instances after the deployment, after that each instance will have it's own modified values

Comment: Each war file is retrieving dB parameters from Web. Xml to be accessible for any classes willing to access dB. But I can see that each singleton of the different war files are  getting the values of the first war deployed

Comment: Each context (war file) will create a different instance of the singleton class. Without anything being different, how do you envision the singleton class to have different values if it is running the exact same code? Did you perhaps specify different values in the Tomcat context.xml file (inside `conf/Catalina/localhost`)?

Comment: well...sorry....I found it very strange and I understand why !....I had a wrong relative path of a servlet, pointing on my initial WAR file, everything is working fine now, sorry for the inconvenience !

Answer (score 4):

Each webapp instance in Tomcat is independent of the others, so if you have multiple webapps deployed, they *will* have different instances of the singleton class. Of course, they will all be configured the same if you don't tell them otherwise.

If you want to run multiple instances of the *same* webapp in a single instance of Tomcat, you can do it simply by creating multiple context XML files. You don't even have to copy the war file.

In `$TOMCAT_HOME$/conf/Catalina/localhost`, create multiple XML files, e.g.

**foo.xml**

```xml
<Context docBase="C:/path/to/MyWepApp.war">
  <Parameter name="greeting" value="Hello from FOO"/>
</Context>
```

**bar.xml**

```xml
<Context docBase="C:/path/to/MyWepApp.war">
  <Parameter name="greeting" value="Hello from BAR"/>
</Context>
```

If your webapp code calls [`ServletContext.getInitParameter("greeting")`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter(java.lang.String)) to get that configuration value, it can now display a different greeting in each deployed instance.

You can now access them using `http://localhost:8080/foo` and `http://localhost:8080/bar`.

When you update the war file, they will both auto-redeploy, without having to restart Tomcat.

Comment: very interesting !